# if click on any leftside box will append to right side first box only

Tags: jquery

if click on any leftside box will append to right side first box only.after filled first box second box will append.
In every right side box should getting only one box.

[image][check this link](https://jsfiddle.net/swaroop206/fc4d7vuj/2/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo('.box2');
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.box{width:50px;height:50px;background:red;margin-bottom:5px;}
.leftbox{width:300px;float:left;}
.box2{width:100px;height:100px;background:#999;float:left;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}

.rightbox{width:900px;height:600px;float:left;border:1px solid #999;overflow:scroll;padding:10px;}
</style>

<div class="leftbox">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
</div>

<div class="rightbox">
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what what I understood you can target each `.box2` one by one using a variable like this:

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fc4d7vuj/4/)**

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    i++;
    $(this).appendTo('.box2:nth-child(' + i + ')');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.leftbox {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rightbox {
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftbox">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
</div>

<div class="rightbox">
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could do is add another class (in this case 'unused') and remove it once the box is added

https://jsfiddle.net/fq7rn3s1/

```
<div class="leftbox">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
</div>

<div class="rightbox">
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
<div class="box2 unused"></div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").click(function(){
    var box2 = $(".rightbox").find(".unused")[0];
    $(box2).removeClass("unused");
    $(this).appendTo($(box2));
    });
});
```